# Temporarily bypassing implicit waits with WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, wait

When using implicit waits, **[as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950905/56285)**,  I still *sometimes* want to assert the **immediate** invisibility or non-existence of elements.

In other words, I *know* some elements should be hidden, and want my tests make that assertion *fast*, without spending several seconds because of the (otherwise useful) implicit wait.

One thing I tried was a helper method like this:

```
// NB: doesn't seem to do what I want
private boolean isElementHiddenNow(String id) {
    WebDriverWait zeroWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0);
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> c = invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id));
    try {
        zeroWait.until(c);
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But in the above code, the call to `until()` only returns **after the implicit wait time has passed**, i.e., it doesn't do what I wanted.

This is the only way I've found so far that works:

```
@Test
public void checkThatSomethingIsNotVisible()  {
    turnOffImplicitWaits();
    // ... the actual test
    turnOnImplicitWaits();
}
```

... where e.g. `turnOffImplicitWaits()` is a helper in common Selenium superclass:

```
protected void turnOffImplicitWaits() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

But that is not very elegant, I think. **Is there any cleaner way to bypass the implicit wait occasionally?**

Comment: I don't believe there is anything defined by the interface that does what you want. The only thing I can think of is to call findElements instead of findElement. But I'm not sure that bypasses the implicit wait either.

Comment: @MikeKwan No, [`findElements()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) also tries to wait and return after at least one element has been found.

Comment: Would be a good case for lambdas
 `public void bypassImplicitWaits(Bypass bypass) {
    turnOffImplicitWaits();
    bypass.do();
    turnOnImplicitWaits();
  }`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Given that Selenium doesn't seem to offer what I want directly (based on what Mike Kwan and Slanec said), this simple helper method is what I went with for now:

```
protected boolean isElementHiddenNow(String id) {
    turnOffImplicitWaits();
    boolean result = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id)).apply(driver);
    turnOnImplicitWaits();
    return result;
}

private void turnOffImplicitWaits() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private void turnOnImplicitWaits() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

If the element is hidden or not present at all, the method returns true; if it is visible, returns false. Either way, the check is done instantly.

Using the above is at least much cleaner than littering the test cases themselves with calls to `turnOffImplicitWaits()`  and `turnOnImplicitWaits()`.

See also these answers for fined-tuned versions of the same approach:

- [Using try-finally to turn implicit waits back on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23359199/56285)
- [Using `By` locator as the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25001911/56285)

Comment: How do you turn on implicit waits?

Comment: @JeffMay: something like `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10950905/56285).

Comment: Use By as an parameter in example so it would be easier and can be used for all :)

Comment: Anybody know how to replicate this line:
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`
in Python? I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: Never mind, you can just set the implicit wait time the same way you initially set it.

Answer (score 7):

I would also suggest changing the parameter to a "By" locator for more flexibility when looking for the element.

```
protected boolean isElementHiddenNow(By locator) {
    turnOffImplicitWaits();
    boolean result = false;
    try {
       result = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator).apply(driver);
    }
    finally {
       turnOnImplicitWaits();
    }
    return result;
}
```

That way, you could search by css if needed rather than just id:

```
By PartLinkLocator = By.cssSelector("div.search-result div.row a");
```

'Course, your locator should probably be designed to return only one element (unlike the "By" example I quickly grabbed, which returns all part links in a css table of rows...) So, an "id" example would look like

```
By usernameLocator = By.id("inputEmail");
myResult = isElementHiddenNow(usernameLocator);
```

Comment: Definitely the try/finally is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

My implementation:

```
using (driver.NoImplicitWait())
{
    ....
}
```

With extension method:

```
public static NoImplicitWait NoImplicitWait(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    return new NoImplicitWait(driver);
}
```

And class:

```
public sealed class NoImplicitWait : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

    public NoImplicitWait(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[@Jonic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047564) helped me, however I would add a `try { } finally { }` and call `turnOnImplicitWaits()` in the `finally` block to make sure it always turns back on.

```
protected boolean isElementHiddenNow(String id) {
    turnOffImplicitWaits();
    boolean result = false;
    try {
       result = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id)).apply(driver);
    }
    finally {
       turnOnImplicitWaits();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to bypass Implicit wait entirely and reimplement it (with an addition of a visibility check etc.) in my own `findElement()` and `findElements()` methods which I now use by default. This way, when I want to check something instantly, I can call the original WebDriver method which does, of course, not wait.

Comment: How do you go about waiting without using the implicitWait option? Did you just implement a try/catch in some kind of loop and poll the element every few second until reaching some threshold?

Comment: @AndyPerfect Yes, the usual (try-catch, try again or timeout) approach with some basic additional feats: visibility, disabled elements, highlighting found elements, workarounds for page not really loaded (starts again on StaleElementReference), temporarily also for [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3800) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3470) bug.

Answer (score 0):

In an existing code relying a lot on implicit wait way of thinking, and without CSS to the rescue,  I found a way out nfor that kind of things, complementing it with Jsoup, and going on with Jsoup:

```
# this is straightforward Scala... put the types and it is Java.
val innerHtml = seleniumWebElementFatherInstance.getAttribute("innerHTML")
val jsoupElements = Jsoup.parse(innerHtml).select("div.your.css.selector")
```

Answer (score 0):

**To override or temporarily skip the implicit wait**. Selenium doesn't provide any direct solution since these are static values.

To achieve that we need a **workaround** as mentioned in this article.
[How to skip the implicit wait for some element in Selenium in JAVA](https://qatestauto.com/how-to-skip-the-implicit-wait-for-some-element-in-selenium-in-java/)