# Selenium WebDriver get(url) speed issue

Tags: java, selenium, asynchronous, webdriver, wait

The get(url) method waits for the web page to be fully loaded. If the page has a lot of stuff on it, loading can be very slow.

Is there a way to navigate to the target web page and wait only for the WebElement of interest? (i.e. not the banners, ads, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Page load timeout](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). As far as I know, this is definitely supported by `FirefoxDriver` and `InternetExplorerDriver`, though I'm not sure about other drivers.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
try {
    driver.get("http://google.com");
} catch (TimeoutException ignored) {
    // expected, ok
}
```

Or you can do a nonblocking page load with JavaScript:

```
private JavascriptExecutor js;

// I like to do this right after driver is instantiated
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
}

// later, in the test, instead of driver.get("http://google.com");
js.executeScript("window.location.href = 'http://google.com'");
```

Both these examples load Google, but they return the control over the `driver` instance back to you immediatelly instead of waiting for the whole page to load. You can then simply wait for the one element you're looking for.

---

In case you didn't want this functionality just on the `WebDriver#get()`, but on you wanted a nonblocking `click()`, too, you can do one of these:

1. Use the page load timeout as shown above.
2. Use [The Advanced User Interactions API](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#advanceduserinteractions) ([JavaDocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html))

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.whatever("anything"));
   new Actions(driver).click(element).perform();
   ```
3. Use JavaScript again:

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.whatever("anything"));
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Following url may help you.

[Temporarily bypassing implicit waits with WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034710/temporarily-bypassing-implicit-waits-with-webdriver)

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4993