# href locator not working in Selenium for only one element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have been writing some selenium scripts whereby I am selecting some options from a drop down list. When I hover over the parent list, it displays a list of children from where I can select an option. This functionality has been working fine for numerous elements, but I have one which is resulting in a 'ElementNotVisibleException'.

I've attached 2 examples of the code I have been using. The top method is working, but the 2nd one I am experiencing issues with. If anyone can help as to why I might be getting this error I would appreciate it.

**WORKS**

```
    public static void creditNoteReportFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'CreditNoteReport')]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

**DOESN'T WORK**

```
public static void earlySettlementWorkflowFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver) throws InterruptedException
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'EarlySettlementMatch?StartUpView=0')]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

**SCREENSHOT**
[image]

**CODE SNIPPET OF HTML**

```
<div class="inner">
    <img alt="barney" runat="server" src="/DibsAndrew/images/chinook/gfx-topnav-left.gif"/>
    <ul class="drop-down-menu sub-nav">
        <li>
        <li>
        <li>
        <li>
            <a class="highlighted" href="/DibsAndrew/CCLReports/Overall">Reports</a>
            <ul id="ddm-86476" style="display: block;">
                <li>
                <li>
                    <a class="highlighted" href="#">Collections</a>
                    <span>»</span>
                    <ul style="display: block;">
                        <li>
                        <li>
                        <li>
                        <li>
                        <li>
                        <li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="highlighted"  href="/DibsAndrew/ETCalculator/EarlySettlementMatch?StartUpView=0">Early Settlement Workflow</a>
                        </li>
```

Comment: Please provide a HTML snippet that shows the element(s) in question so we can help you out, thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark, details are now attached. Thanks

Comment: Screenshots are **useless** for showing code! In your second XPath, what are the asterisks **outside** of the single-quotations suppose to be?

Comment: Simon, please no longer comment on my questions as I am fed up of your sarcastic and condescending responses. many thanks

Comment: Wonder if the question mark symbol is throwing off the XPath. Have you tried using different text in the contains to see if the element is being found? As an example `By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'EarlySettlementMatch')]")`

Comment: Hi Shri, thanks for the response. It's very odd, even when I remove the question mark I still get the error......but, again, only on this element

Comment: Oh the exception stems from the element not being visible. For some reason I thought it was element not found exception. It is possible that the code executes before the element becomes visible in case of dynamic nature of the menu. Try adding a wait for visibility as mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941184/equivalent-of-waitforvisible-waitforelementpresent-in-selenium-webdriver-tests-u).

Comment: There is some way to make that element visible. Selenium will not perform any action on the element that is not visible. I can pretty much tell your item is not visible so use some `wait` for the element to be visible

Comment: Hi, thanks for both of your comments. I've now added a webdriver wait and applied a time limit of 30 seconds, but after this time the element is not visible. The one thing that is different on this element, compared to ones that have previously worked is that it has a '?' in it, as follows                               'EarlySettlementMatch?StartUpView=0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to use absolute xpath in order to resolve this.