# Custom timeout in "WaitForElementPresent" command on Selenium

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I'm using a lot the "WaitForElementPresent" command in Selenium IDE, when I intentionally run a bad script on Jenkins it stops during 30 seconds because an element does not appear, but I want to make that modify this 30 seconds to 5 seconds, so...how could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941184/equivalent-of-waitforvisible-waitforelementpresent-in-selenium-webdriver-tests-u

Comment: @ekuusela Yes, I found that too but it does not helped me because I'm working only in html, but I found the solution: Put the command setTimeOut=5000, so every "WaitFor..." command will wait 5 seconds.