# Unable to proceed with login in google using selenium

Tags: eclipse

I am trying selenium webdriver for the first time.
Want to login in gmail and wrote a program for the same.
The code is providing the email id and proceeding further, but it is not entering the password. PFB my program. Can someone help on this?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium Jar Files\\Selenium Jar Files\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        String i = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(i);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        driver.switchTo().frame("gaia_loginform");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("abc@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```

Comment: Anyone up there for help?

Answer (score 0):

[Gmail login fail using Selenium webdriver. Showing element not found for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318653/gmail-login-fail-using-selenium-webdriver-showing-element-not-found-for-passwor)

**Explanation**

> The reason selenium can't find the element is because
>   the id of the password input field is initially Passwd-hidden. After
>   you click on the "Next" button, Google first verifies the email
>   address entered and then shows the password input field (by changing
>   the id from Passwd-hidden to Passwd). So, when the password field is
>   still hidden (i.e. Google is still verifying the email id), your
>   webdriver starts searching for the password input field with id Passwd
>   which is still hidden. And hence, an exception is thrown."