# How to set value in hidden textbox using selenium java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

How to set value in hidden textbox using selenium java. It throws the following error, "Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only...". I tried many methods like using sendkeys, using js excute but nothing works out. Please refer the following code in my script,

Method:1

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("editbox")).sendKeys(input);
```

Method:2

```
driver.findElement(By.id("editbox")).setAttribute("value", "your value");
```

Method 3:

```
WebElement Element = driver.findElement(By.id("editbox"))
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", Element, input);
```

Comment: Did you try to make it visible?

Comment: Hi @Andersson, I'm new to selenium. Can you please tell me how to make it visible

Comment: You can wait for [visibility of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941184/equivalent-of-waitforvisible-waitforelementpresent-in-selenium-webdriver-tests-u) or [scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium) to make it visible

Comment: @Andersson, I tried this. It shows that the object is visible. Click using js is working in that object but there is problem only with 'set'

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and the exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_.

Comment: @DebanjanB I need to set value in an edit box. The edit box HTML structure is,

<td>
<div class = "class-name" id = "id1234">    ...  </div>

Answer (score 0):

The quick way of doing this is by using js, this is an answer using python with selenium:

```
    # Test that captcha response field is in the page
    captcha_response = driver.find_element_by_id(LocatorsFirstPage.FORM_CAPTCHA_RESPONSE_ID)


    # Make captcha response visible to input response
    driver.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="";')

    # Set captcha response
    driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = arguments[0]', result)
    driver.find_element_by_id("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML=result

    print(captcha_response.get_attribute("value"))
```

Then you can make it not visible by setting the style to "display: none;" the same way using js.

Answer (score -1):

Is your invisible element going to be visible at some point or is permanently invisible? If the element is visible after some time, you can wait to it's visibility:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityofelement(by.id(...
```